# Glide - No display image from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

I am creating app which display posts on main view. After add new post we see only text no images.

I trie use picasso and glide. But with no result.

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PostList> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PostList>().setQuery(query, PostList.class).build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostList, PostListHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostList, PostListHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        public PostListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_row, parent, false);
            return new PostListHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostListHolder holder, int position, @NonNull PostList model) {
            holder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage(), holder);
            holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            holder.setDescription(model.getDescription());

        }
    };

        void setImage(Context ctx, String image) {

            ImageView postImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.postImg);
            Glide.with(ctx).load(image).dontAnimate().fitCenter().into(postImage);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is with this line:
`ImageView postImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.postImg);`

you are not using your  `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` image and you are just using some image that is not associated to your current reyclerVie row, so glide is actually working but you are not using the proper image.

You need to do something similar to this:

```
  holder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage(),yourHolder);
```

And access your holder.imageView from the method:

```
void setImage(Context ctx, String image,ViewHolder holder) {  
  Glide.with(ctx).load(image).dontAnimate().fitCenter().into(holder.postImage);
}
```

Comment: I would love to help you out, but could you elaborate on why is this not correct?